# How to apply diagnostic prediction model to new data

Tags: r, coefficients, lasso-regression

With some help I performed LASSO regression on boostrapped and multiple imputed datasets to build a diagnostic model that can distinguish disease A from disease B using a large number of predictor variables.

Eventually, I have the following table with the selected variables (which are all categorical variables with yes/no  as outcome) and their coefficients:

| **Predictor** | **mean regression coefficient** |
| --- | --- |
| Intercept | 10.141 |
| var1 | 1.671 |
| Var2 | -1.971 |
| Var3 | -5.266 |
| Var4 | -2.244 |
| Var5 | 5.266 |

My question is: how can I use above table to predict wether a new patient (that has not been used to build te model) has disease A or disease B.

I thought of the following:

Intercept + (1.671 (var1) x 0 or 1) - (1.971 (var2) x 0 or 1) - (5.266 (var3) x 0 or 1) ..... + (5.266 (var5) x 0  or 1)  = X

Probability of having disease A (which was coded as 1 in the dataset) = e^X / (1+ e^X)

But is this approach correct?

I hope someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since you are describing logistic regression, the steps are correct. These are the steps to calculating a prediction from your model.

a) Multiply coefficients by x variables, making sure to include the intercept if applicable (with value of 1)

b) Sum the results of a)

c) Exponentiate to produce log odds

d) Calculate final probability with log_odds / (1 + log_odds)

You didn't mention a specific language, but here's some pseudo-code in `python` using `pandas/numpy`, assuming a dataset `x_variables` and a pandas `series` of `coefficients`.

```py
scores = x_variables.transpose()
scores = transpose_predictors.mul(coefficients, axis = 0)
sum_scores = scores.sum(axis = 0, skipna = True)
log_odds = np.exp(sum_scores)
final_scores = log_odds / (1 + log_odds)
```

Edit: Same code in `R`, where `coefficients` is a vector of the coefficient values.

```
# do the scoring via matrix multiplication
scores <- t(t(x_variables) * coefficients)

# sum the scores by row and exponentiate. 
log_odds <- exp(rowSums(scores, na.rm = TRUE))
final_scores <- log_odds / (1 + log_odds)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! I am not familiar with python, but can you give the above code in R? much appreciated. Also, in step a) from your response: So wether the coefficients are a negative or a positive value, I should substract or add from the intercept, respectively right?

Comment: No problem, I edited to add the equivalent R code. And it's technically all adding, but when you multiply by a negative coefficient, that sign will flow through so you'll be adding a negative number (like in the case of your Var2). So functionally it becomes subtraction in those instances.